# regular expression the words

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

my requirement is like I have sentence which I want to convert into multiple lines

Input 1 :  my name is **abc:xyz:pqr**

output1:
        . my name is **abc**
        . my name is **xyz**
        . my name is **pqr**

INPUT 2 : **xyz:abc** is a student

OUTPUT2 : 
        . **xyz** is a student
        . **abc** is a student

INPUT 3: class B students **abc:xyz** is playing

OUTPUT 3:
        . class B students **abc** is playing
        . class B students **Xyz** is playing

Answer (score 0):

Try with `re`:

```py
import re

txt="class B students abc:xyz is playing"

for el in re.finditer(r"[^\s]+(:[^\s]+)+", txt):
    x=el.span()
    y=el[0]
    for opt in y.split(":"):
        print(txt[:x[0]]+opt+txt[x[1]:])
```

Outputs:

```py
class B students abc is playing
class B students xyz is playing
```